# Does having a temper make you angry or calm?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Are we using the word "temper" correctly?

Usually when someone is said to "have a temper", we interpret that to mean they are quick to anger or are prone to outbursts of anger.

However I'm wondering if this is the wrong way around. To "temper" something usually means to cool it down or quench it. A temperate climate is cool but not too cold.

Indeed we also say of someone who had a particular bout of anger that they "*lost* their temper".

So if someone "has a temper", should that not mean they are cool headed or good at keeping calm in the face of provocation?

Comment: Whether it 'should' or not makes no difference to the way language is used. I suppose 'having a temper' is short for 'having a _bad_ or a _quick_ temper'.

Comment: Very often we say someone **has a bad temper**, and someone **is good-tempered**

Comment: In metallurgy, *tempering* is a process involving heat.

Comment: Language is what it is, not what somebody thinks it ought to be.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/temper#etymonline_v_7705

Comment: @Mari-LouA temper, in the sense of disposition, meant a good thing (moderated, within limits) first. Bad temper followed, and must have perjorated the root. Temperate and temperamental is an interesting pair, since they seem to have different meanings.

Comment: @colmde, of course we are using it correctly! :) Words _describe_ meaning, rather than set it in stone. If everyone uses 'temper' to mean angry, that's what 'temper' means.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Strictly speaking, words do not ‘describe’ meaning:  they ‘convey’ it.

Comment: "Temper" is one of those words where idiomatic use has created paradoxes in the way it is used. Another is "inflammable" which used in one sense means that something easily catches fire, in another that it is not capable of flaming. Sense and meaning so often depend upon context and idiom.

Comment: @Tuffy I was referring to descriptivism

Comment: @marcellothearcane Descriptivism is an ethical theory about the nature of discourse about values.  I do not see any connection between that and the question or to your comment on it.

Comment: @Tuffy https://www.thoughtco.com/descriptivism-language-term-1690441

Comment: @nnnnnn - indeed, but in a very controlled manner - and the process is to reduce brittleness.

Comment: Questions about etymology are inappropriate to this forum

Answer (score 0):

Think of temper as a *measurement*, rather than a state. It's rather like the related word, 'temperature'. It's possible to have a 'good temper', a 'bad temper', a 'mild temper', and [many other variations](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/temper) (see 'more example sentences).

To add to the 'temperature' analogy, the word is commonly used thus:

> She had a temperature, so had to stay at home.

It *implies* that her temperature was high, because *that's how it's most commonly used*. The same can be said for temper:

> What a temper she has!

This implies that her temper is bad (not temperate, if you will. Possibly temperamental). This is also because without a modifier, you can assume it means the negative sense.

Comment: You simply restate the OP's question in different words. However I do agree with @Colin Fine's point that "language is what it is, not what someone thinks it should be".

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your understanding of what tempering is in relation to metalworking.

Quenching a hot piece of metal is not tempering; it is hardening.

[Tempering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempering_(metallurgy)) is taking a piece of metal and raising the temperature to a level high enough to relieve the stresses in the hardened metal, but lower than the temperature required to work it with a hammer/tool, and then slowly cooling it down.

So, it makes sense that if someone has a temper and it means they metaphorically get hot and are slow to cool down.

Answer (score -1):

Logically, I believe you are correct: a "temper" is a good thing that should not be lost, and "having (a) temper" taken literally means roughly the same as "having self-control": it should make you calm. However, in modern usage, "Having a temper" is always shorthand for "having a *bad* temper", as in poor self-control, specifically poor control over anger.

Older literature sometimes described people as "temper*ate*", meaning "controlled" or "moderate". There are [a few examples](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=temperate&version=KJV) in the King James version of the Bible, for instance. Similarly, [Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temper) has "*a suitable proportion or balance of qualities : a middle state between extremes*" as an "archaic" meaning of temper.

It is this sense of temper that you see in a *temperate* climate: not too hot or too cold, but moderate. Similarly, *tempering* metal means achieving the desired balance between hardness and brittleness: making a tool that can hold an edge without shattering requires significant skill for a blacksmith, or careful design and control in a foundry.